# Flutter Firebase Firestore: Upgrade options works incorrectly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I learn work with Firebase Firestore, and now face with one problem and don't know how to solute this problem. When I first add item its works fine, when I tried to update exist item, its just update in all ads where i have for example 'title', how to update using current unique key, and only there, not in all another keys?. Maybe its possible send saved key to another screen and paste it inside doc path for updating?  Thanks for help in advance!

At screen for add ad, add code ->

```
  

  CollectionReference ads = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ads');
 Future<void> newAdd(){
     return ads.add({
     'title' : titlecontroller.text,
     'phone' : phonecontroller.text,
     'price' : pricecontroller.text,
     'desc'  : desccontroller.text,
     'category'  : categoryCurrentItem,
     'userid'  : user != null? user!.uid : googleUser!.id,
     'time'   : Timestamp.now()

   });
  }
```

At screen for updating add, update code :

```
CollectionReference updateads = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ads');
Future<void> UpdateAdd(){
    Future<void> UpdateAdd(){
    GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
     return updateads
      .get()
      .then((querysnapshot) => querysnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
         updateads.doc(element.id).update({
           'title' : widget.titletext,
           'phone' : widget.phonetext,
           'price' : widget.pricetext,
           'desc'  : widget.desctext,
           'category'  : categoryCurrentItem,
           'userid'  : user != null? user!.uid : googleUser!.id,
           'time'   : Timestamp.now()
         });
       }));
  }
```

Comment: Did you check that if user.uid or googleUser.uid returns null? If you provide null variable to doc('id'), the key will be given by Firestore randomly.

Comment: I already done logic, that if user.uid or googleuser. id equals to null, so user can 't add or update anything in all app. So i make update function only in case if im already sign in

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for someone its going be useful,finally i understand how it works.

When u fetched data, every item has index, and where you want to update you must parse documentsnapshots index. Its mean add to constructor docsnapshot in class when you would like to make editing process, and got it from activity where u fetched data.
Here is an example =>

Class where you would like to update ->

```
class EditAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  String titletext;
  String pricetext;
  String phonetext;
  String desctext;
  *this doc will save current key - DocumentSnapshot doc;

  EditAdd(this.titletext, this.pricetext, this.phonetext, this.desctext,this.doc);
```

And where you should get this value

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: adsStream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(
                child: Text('Loading...'),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  DocumentSnapshot ads = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                   final userad = (ads.data()as dynamic)['userid'];
                  return Ads((ads.data() as dynamic)['title'], (ads.data() as dynamic)['price'],
                      userad == user?.uid || userad ==  googleUser?.id  ?  IconButton(
                          onPressed: userad == user?.uid || userad ==  googleUser?.id  ?() async{
                            bool result = await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
                            try {
                              if(result == true) {
                                showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context){
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text('Warning'),
                                    content: Text('Do you really want to delete ad?'),
                                    actions: [
                                      TextButton(onPressed: ()async{
                                        await collectionads.doc(ads.id).delete();
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text('Ad deleted'));
                                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
                                      }, child: Text('Yes')),
                                      TextButton(onPressed: (){
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }, child: Text('No') )
                                    ],
                                  );

                                });
                              } else {
                                final snackbarerror = SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('Internet connection is lost'));
                                
                           
                           
                       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbarerror);
                              }
                            } on Exception catch (e) {
                              print(e);
                            }

                          } : null,
                          icon: userad == user?.uid || userad == googleUser?.id ? 
                     Icon(Icons.delete) : Icon(null)

                      ) : null,
                      userad == user?.uid || userad == googleUser?.id? IconButton(
                          icon: userad == user?.uid || userad == googleUser?.id? 
                          Icon(Icons.edit) : Icon(null) ,
                          onPressed:(){
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
                                   (context)
                            => EditAdd((ads.data() as dynamic)['title'],
                                (ads.data() as dynamic)['price'],
                                (ads.data() as dynamic)['phone'],
                                (ads.data() as dynamic)['desc'],*!ads)));
                          }
                      ) : null

                       );

                });
          }
        )
```

and Finally how to update ->

```
//You have to parse this docsnapshot, get reference and all fine will update

return widget.doc.reference.update({
      'title' : widget.titletext,
      'phone' : widget.phonetext,
      'price' : widget.pricetext,
      'desc'  : widget.desctext,
      'category'  : categoryCurrentItem,
      'userid'  : user != null? user!.uid : googleUser!.id,
      'time'   : Timestamp.now()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you try to merge a document with new data. To do that, you need to define SetOptions in set function.

```
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
db.collection('users').doc(id).set({
  'name': name,
}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

If you give a path to document, and still Firebase creates another document and not rewriting to existing document, you maybe give it null variable to document id. That's why Firebase creates a different id for that document.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I upgraded my questions, maybe now its going be more clarity what i want. Im beginner and sometimes explain is too hard) Also updated code, i found some solution to get this unique key, but now its update in all keys when i have 'title' or etc. All logic with fetch data in Stream builder, delete, sorted by category i did so fast, but stuck with update data so much)